# Reledmac Tabular Numbering

Tags: reledmac

I'm exploring the reledmac package. I want to number a tabular environment.

Now, I came across their sample source code for this, and for some reason it is not working.

This is what I found in their documentation on page 72:

```
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{edtabularl}
\textbf{\Large I} & wish I was a little bug\edindex{bug} &
\textbf{\Large I} & eat my peas with honey\edindex{honey} \\
& With whiskers \edtext{round}{\Afootnote{around}} my tummy &
& I’ve done it all my life. \\
& I’d climb into a honey\edindex{honey} pot &
& It makes the peas taste funny \\
& And get my tummy gummy.\edindex{gummy} &
& But it keeps them on the knife.
\end{edtabularr}
\pend
\endnumbering
```

The error I get is the following:

> ! Paragraph ended before \edtabularl was complete. 
> \par  l.34
> ?

Interestingly, the source code works when I remove the numbering macros...But that's how it is written in the documentation?!

Again, I'm just curious if anybody has any ideas of what's going on.

Comment: I was getting the error "Paragraph ended before \edtabularl was complete..." because I left an empty line between the environment commands (\begin... and \end{edtabular*}) and the tabular content.

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo. You must replace `end{edtabularr}` with `end{edtabularl}`.

Comment: Actually, the typo is in the documentation itself. I've tired both ways with and without the typo.

Comment: weel, without the typo, I have no problem. I will look on the documentation and correct it. Please open a issue

Comment: I think I figured out what is happening. I noticed none of the lines displayed the number until line 5. That is, only every fifth line is printed. I have this minimal work example: ```\begin{document}
\beginnumbering %it seems this is displaying every fifth number...
\pstart
\begin{edtabularl}
λόγος & λόγος & λόγος\\
\edtext{λαχολ}{\Afootnote{test}}   & λόγος & λόγος\\
λόγος & λόγος & λόγος\\
λόγος & λόγος & λόγος\\
λόγος & λόγος & λόγος
\end{edtabularl}
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}```

Comment: yes, that is the default setting of reledmac, we typeset line every fifth number. It is explained in the handbook. Please read § 5.3.2 of the handbook...